# Sub categories Hierarchy

Tags: php, mysql

I designed a SQL structure to represent categories and their subcategories.

I have 3 tables:

```
articles
articles_categories
categories
```

Articles table:

```
id,title,content
```

Categories table:

```
id, title, parent_id
```

articles_categories:

```
id,article_id,category_id
```

No problem with SQL, but now - lets say i'm on article id 5
article id 5 has - 3 categories, that 2 of them has parents, and the main has '0' as parent.

How do I fetch them all efficiently? (lets say for - breadcrumbs).

thanks!

Comment: is `article`-`category` `many to many` to relation. If it is then i would go for Ronnis answer

Answer (score 3):

Unless the depth of the category hierarchy is fixed, you cannot do this in MySQL with your current model (adjacency list). You'd have to traverse the hierarchy using several SQL statements in a loop.

If the category hierarchy is fairly static, you can "precompute" the tree by using:

- Path enumeration
- Nested sets
- Closure table

All of the above, trades write performance for read performance. 
Google or search SO for any of the above and you will find examples of how to implement it.

Quite often, I find that storing the data in a adjacency list (because of best matches the data model) and caching a copy of the tree in the application is good enough, but that depends on your requirements of course :)

Comment: *Good enough* will do when it's an emergency! :) Thanks, I use CI which already takes care of caching, so I'll just stick to adjacency list - I did read up on "preorder tree traversal" method, but there is simply no time to translate that in to code right now...

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
select * from articles_categories 
left join categories on categories.id = articles_categories.category_id 
where article_id=1;

+------+------------+-------------+------+--------+-----------+
| id   | article_id | category_id | id   | title  | parent_id |
+------+------------+-------------+------+--------+-----------+
| NULL |          1 |           1 |    1 | first  |         0 |
| NULL |          1 |           2 |    2 | second |         1 |
| NULL |          1 |           3 |    3 | third  |         2 |
+------+------------+-------------+------+--------+-----------+
```

Additionally, I would remove the "id" column from associative table `articles_categories`.